# Invalid file name for Source image - cannot change without missing message

Tags: android, xamarin

hope you can help!

I have a xamarin Android app with a default source image - Default-Portrait@2x and when I run my app it complains about the special characters however when I remove them it then complains about the old file name with the special characters being missing.

How can I resolve this and stop the compiler from looking for 'Default-Portrait@2x' ?

Comment: Can't you just change the name?

Comment: Well I tried that but as I said, it then complains about the old name I changed it from being missing with the special characters

Comment: Have you updated the file of the name and any reference to it?

Comment: Resources/drawable/Default-Portrait@2x.png: Error XA2001: Source file 'Resources/drawable/Default-Portrait@2x.png' could not be found. (XA2001)

Comment: @JuanSturla I'm not sure where it's being referenced to, I've changed it in the project file but it doesnt tell me where else its being referred to!

Comment: /R.java: Error APT2258: invalid symbol name 'com.myapp:drawable/default'. (APT2258) (myapp.Android)

Comment: Could you try changing the name to lowercases and without "-" (you can use "_" ) ?

Comment: delete it and re-add it with a valid name

Comment: Delete the bin and obj folder in the project , delete the app from the device , rebuild and clean .